# Is it possible to generate apk for pwa

Tags: reactjs, apk

- We are building a PWA app using React framework. Is it really possible to generate a apk of the pwa app ? I came across some site but the issue happens is the address bar is present if I convert it into apk.
- Came across various blogs but in all the address bar is present after the apk is successfully installed.
- And on the other hand if I do `Add to home screen` from chrome it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It's very much possible. Once I have tried this and succeed. You need to setup an Android studio and follow step by step from the link given below.

[Google Developer Guide](https://web.dev/using-a-pwa-in-your-android-app/)

If you face address bar issue then you need to register your PWA as trusted and ownership verification. [Here is the link](https://web.dev/using-a-pwa-in-your-android-app/#verifying-ownership-of-the-pwa-in-the-android-app)

Answer (score -4):

No.

A PWA is not an application which runs natively on any device. You'd need to compile your reactjs to some sort of native thing.

You may take a look at [PhoneGap](https://phonegap.com/) or, if you're flagrant enough, you may just wrap your PWA into a WebView of any app framework of your liking.